# How quit the Ndepend report into the Build Report?

Tags: cruisecontrol.net, ndepend

I want to quit the Ndepend report into the Build Report, but still have the link 
‘NDepend Report” in link in the left navigation.
How can I do that?

thanks!

Alejandra

Answer (score 2):

The online documentation for CruiseControl.NET covers most of the details on how to integrate NDepend with CruiseControl.NET. http://confluence.public.thoughtworks.org/display/CCNET/Using+CruiseControl.NET+with+NDepend

The file to change is dashboard.config. The *<buildPlugins>* element contains all the links in the left hand menu. To add or remove a link you'll need to add the relevant element, in this case the following:

```
<xslReportBuildPlugin 
   description="NDepend Report" 
   actionName="NDependBuildReport" 
   xslFileName="xsl\ndependreport-ccnet.v2.xsl" />
```

To remove the NDepend report from the main report you'll need to modify the *<buildReportBuildPlugin>* element. Find the following element and remove it:

```
<xslFile>xsl\ndependreport-ccnet.v2.xsl</xslFile>
```

Hopefully this answers your question.

Craig